# Dataset not being filled

Tags: c#

the follwing functions gives me an error:

```
FillFields("select Housemcode,Name, HP,Rateperhour ,Resource_H_Code FROM House_Machinery where Housemcode like '" + sSearch + "'");


public void FillFields(string sSQL)
    {
        sCommands.setSqldbCommand(sVariables.sDataSet, sVariables.sSqlDbDataAdapter, sSQL, "House_Machinery");
        DataRow sDataRow = sVariables.sDataSet.Tables["House_Machinery"].Rows[0];
        txtItemName.Text = sDataRow["Name"].ToString();
        txtrate.Text = sDataRow["HP"].ToString();
        txtrate.Text = sDataRow["Rateperhour"].ToString();
        Variables.StrResourceHeaderCode = sDataRow["Resource_H_Code"].ToString();

    }
```

the error is:
There is no row at position 0.

can any one give an insight on this?

Comment: What is this !> what are you trying to do ?

Comment: Also, what's this `sVariables` stuff? Very strange way to code.

Comment: @kunal are you trying to import data from table and loading textbox with the information ?

Comment: i have got my problems, it was actually not getting any rows from above query I'll let u know as I get get through it.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is simply not returning any rows. Try running the SQL query directly in SQL Management Studio to confirm that data is returned.

Incidentally, you can check whether any data is returned at run-time by counting the rows returned:

```
sCommands.setSqldbCommand(sVariables.sDataSet, sVariables.sSqlDbDataAdapter, sSQL, "House_Machinery");
if(sVariables.sDataSet.Tables["House_Machinery"].Rows.Count == 0)
   throw new Exception("No matching rows found");
DataRow sDataRow = sVariables.sDataSet.Tables["House_Machinery"].Rows[0];
```

Comment: Per codebrain you probably intended to have % in your LIKE. e.g. LIKE '%search_text%'

Answer (score 0):

```
1.Just check with Breakpoints if it works well,
2.Does your Sql query working in sql server ? check that it may circle it out.
3.Check your wildcard "%like%",this may have issues.


 void somewhereelse()
{
  string qry = "select Housemcode,Name, HP,Rateperhour ,Resource_H_Code FROM House_Machinery    where Housemcode like '" + sSearch + "'";
  filldetails(qry);
}


protected void filldetails(string someqry)
{
  Sqlconnection conn = new SqlConnection("Connectionstring");      
  Datatable dt = new Datatable();
  try
   { 
    conn.Open();
    SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(someqry,conn);
    dap.fill(dt);
    if(dt.rows.count >0)
      {
       txtItemName.Text = dt.rows.[0]["Name"].ToString();
       txtrate.Text = dt.rows.[0]["HP"].ToString();
       txtrate.Text = dt.rows.[0]["Rateperhour"].ToString();
      }

   }
 catch
   {
     throw;
   }
 finally
   {
     if(conn!= null)
      {
        conn.close();
       }
   }
```

Comment: yes thanks, m working on it, it also has some different issues